# MatLab Want function to take in multiple values and output multiple values

Tags: matlab

I have an equation r that I want to take in values from Ex and Vt. Ex and Vt give multiple values when run, but r does not. I need r to give values for each number in x1 and xL1.

Thanks.

```
Es= 1.01911;
Vab= 1.6;
s= 75.5;

x1= [93.5, 93.1, 92.0, 91.9, 92.2];
xL1= [49.0, 46.2, 48.6, 46.3, 48.9];

Ex= x1*(Vab/100);
Vt= Es*(xL1/s);
r=(20*(Ex-Vt))/Vt
```

Comment: I don't think this works. It is displaying a single value for r and the rest are the values for x1.

Comment: well first create 1 empty matrix of size 5.

Comment: Loop through the arrays Ex and Vt and set r. Set Ex and Vt to those arrays prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are after might be element-wise operation, i.e.,

```
r=(20*(Ex-Vt))./Vt
```

such that

```
r =

   25.237   27.773   24.877   27.055   24.699
```